# opensource videoconference soft

Tags: video-conferencing

I am looking for a piece of open source software or library which can do the following:

1. Working a mux on client side (like a Skype/iChat videoconference (more than two callers at a time))
2. Supports STUN or another NAT traversal mechanism.

I don't need BigBlueButton, WebEx, or their analogues.

Comment: But you DO need propietary codecs so that it interacts with otehr such software, which cost licensing fees, or?

Comment: First of all i need the access to code to make some adoptation and additional relevant to education .

Comment: http://www.h323plus.org/

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.h323plus.org/ - an open source H323 library.

http://opensips.org/ - open source SIP.

Covers both major standards.

Comment: ok.But due the nat and perfomance problems i think most good solutions is IAX2 protocol use. But is it possible to use jingle in video conference ?

Comment: Ah, no, sorry. IAX2 is limited to local lines and totally non standard. Pretty much everyne outside asterix talks SIP. Plus, sorry, SIP has neithera NAT nor a perforance problem as it doesn ot deal with transfer data - it only sets thigns up for RTP streams.

Comment: Anyhow, you want IAX2 - get asterix and get learning.

Comment: ок, but what about the jitsi and jingle nodes . Are there support third-person videoconference.